# Libevent aerospike client::Is it possible to register Aerospike FDs in my event handling mechanism

Tags: c++, epoll, libevent, aerospike

I have implemented my own event handling mechanism using epoll so that I have a thread running already. I just want to register the Aerospike FDs in my event loop. Is it possible to do so ? or will it spawn a new thread?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, NO. By design, the FDs are not exposed outside the API. Aerospike's driver maintain its own connection pool for every discovered node and uses them on demand. It spawns its own thread to do the activity.